# printing the largest single-precision floating point number

Tags: c++, c, printf, ieee-754

I have come seeking knowledge.
I am trying to understand floating point numbers.
I am trying to figure out why, when I print the largest floating point number, it does not print correctly.

```
2-(2^-23)                          Exponent Bits
1.99999988079071044921875 * (1.7014118346046923173168730371588e+38) = 
    3.4028234663852885981170418348451e+38
```

This should be the largest single-precision floating point number:

```
340282346638528859811704183484510000000.0
```

So,

```
float i = 340282346638528859811704183484510000000.0;
printf(TEXT, "Float %.38f", i);
Output: 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.0
```

Obviously the number is being rounded up, so I am trying to figure out just exactly what is going on.

My questions are: 
The Wikipedia documentation states that `3.4028234663852885981170418348451e+38` is the largest number that can be represented in IEEE-754 fixed point.

Is the number stored in the floating point register = `0 11111111 11111111111111111111111` and it is just not being displayed incorrectly?

If I write `printf(TEXT, "Float %.38f", FLT_MAX);`, I get the same answer.
Perhaps the computer I am using does not use IEEE-754?

I understand errors with calculations, but I don't understand why the number
`340282346638528860000000000000000000000.0` is the largest floating point number that can be accurately represented.

Maybe the Mantissa * Exponent is causing calculation errors? If that is true, then `340282346638528860000000000000000000000.0` would be the largest number that can be faithfully represented without calculation errors. I guess that would make sense. Just need a blessing.

Thanks,

Comment: "0 11111111 11111111111111111111111" is NAN.  Suspect you want "0 11111110 11111111111111111111111"

Comment: `FLT_MAX` is what you think it is.  Your `printf()` is showing an approximation of it.  To see what _exactly_ is the decimal value of `FLT_MAX`, you need to use different code.

Comment: Wikipedia also says "This gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision" so in everyday use as an approximation of some nearby value, trying to print all the digits as if it was a specific integer at that magnitude's a bit silly.  None of the previous 10^~30 integers were representable.  It's interesting though that printf is showing about the number of digits that would generally be meaningful in a double-precision value - my guess is your implementation casts the float to double, generates a reasonable representation of that, and pads with 0s to the requested length.

Comment: @Tony D  `printf(TEXT, "Float %.38f", i);` converts `i` from `float` to `double` before passing it to `printf()`.  `printf()` does not receive `float`.

Comment: @chux: ah yes of course... so it would be unreasonable to display less precision than that... and evidently the implementation feels pointless to display more.

Comment: Start here:
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/float-precision-revisited-nine-digit-float-portability/

Comment: What is `TEXT` in `printf(TEXT, ...`?

Comment: printf(TEXT, ... is a mistake. it should have been sprintf, then printf(TEXT); I manually copied the code from a different computer...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like culprit is `printf()` (I guess because `float` is implicitly converted to `double` when passed to it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision( 38 );
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
3.4028234663852885981170418348451692544e+38
```

Comment: I am going to have to try that. If that is the value, then it has to be the printf() statement.

Comment: The answer I am getting using your code is slightly different. 34028234663852887000...
So it must be a difference with compiler/computer. Did, or could you try it with the printf() statement?

Comment: Re "I guess because float is implicitly converted ...":  A `float` object` passed to `printf()`, which does undergo conversion to `double`,  does not change the _value_ printed.  Part of the issue is what `printf()` does, but it is not due to the implied conversion.

Answer (score 4):

With `float` as [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32), the largest finite `float` is

> 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0

`printf("%.1f", FLT_MAX)` is not obliged to print exactly to 38+ significant digits, so seeing output like the below is not unexpected.

> 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.0

`printf()` will print floating point accurately to `DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits.   `DECIMAL_DIG` is at *least* 10. If more than `DECIMAL_DIG` significance is directed, a compliant `printf()` may round the result at some point. C11dr §7.21.6.1 6 goes into detail.

Comment: Interesting then that the question claimed it was 340282346638528859811704183484510000000.0 - but the value's less inciddental given the question's really seeking an explanation of the far lesser precision shown by printf.  Nice answer.  I suspect printf() may be allowed to display more, or even obliged... just this specific implementation choosing not to... but I haven't found a reference.

Comment: @Tony D  Found the spec and amended the post.  The spec is a bit technical, so I did not quote it, but IMO, it implies that at least `DECIMAL_DIG` digits must be accurately presentable.  It more significant digits are shown, they must be correct (either of the bounding next highest or next lowest).

Comment: oh cool - good to know.  You were all over this question :-).  Cheers.

Comment: Slava use cout and got the correct answer, so it must be the printf() statement. I have not verified the validity, but between his post and yours about "printf may round and some point". That must be the reason. Thanks

Comment: @Christopher J. Holland  Yes, `printf()` needs to only print up to `DECIMAL_DIG` (from `<float.h>`) significant digits, after that it may just be zeros.  Different platforms provide various levels of precision.  Note: the next smaller `float` before `FLT_MAX` is 340282326356119256160033759537265639424.0, so once one gets pass the 8 MSDigit the remaining digits rapidly lose importance.